# Using tabs.executeScript in iframe

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to implement an extension that can auto fill all fields in an application website. Currently it works great in main frame, but doesn't work if the fields are in a iframe.
I'm allowing users to either use content script to auto inject JS or click a button to inject JS manually.

The problem I have is my JS is not injecting into iframe even I set allFrames to true, but content script work.

```
"content_scripts" : [
        {   
            "matches" : ["https://*/my_url/*"],
            "js" : ["/auto_fill.js"],
            "all_frames": true
        }
]
```

**This content scripts work fine**, JS is being injected. However,

```
my_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file : "/auto_fill.js",
        allFrames : true
    })
});
```

**This executeScript doesn't work**, nothing happen.
The iframe I'm trying to work with is kinda a dynamic iframe (where I have to click few buttons to load and navigate to the application site I want)
Do I have to find out the iframe id or tab id in order for this to work, please provide some hints.

Please let me know if I'm not making myself clear.

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Assuming you want to inject into the active tab (`null` parameter), the two snippets should be entirely equivalent, otherwise it looks like a bug in Chrome. That said, you can add `matchAboutBlank: true` to run in dynamic iframes without a proper URL.

Comment: Thank you for your help @wOxxOm. However, the issue is not in content script, the issue is in second snippets where I'm allowing user to click a button to run the auto_fill script

Comment: Sounds like you think I didn't understand the issue, but I do. See the [documentation for matchAboutBlank](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript).

Comment: I'm really sorry, I was looking at match_about_blank instead of matchAboutBlank. However, even with matchAboutBlank set to true, it is still not working. My iframe is in fact opening another link, but since it is still within the active tab, I cannot understand what is going on, maybe I need to reexamine this iframe that I'm working with.

Comment: Are you using `"activeTab"` permission? It's limited to the main URL of the tab so iframes with different sites won't be processed.

Comment: Yes! I'm using the activeTab permission to allow the chrome.tabs.executeScript to run in active tab. Is there anyway to work around this? Support main URL and iframes?

Comment: No, they intentionally disabled it in Chrome 45, see https://crbug.com/826433.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think we can close this question, would you like to post an answer to this so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments revealed, the extension is using the [activeTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) permission without host URL patterns (just as the documentation suggests), but this permission only grants access to the tab's main URL. When an iframe points to a different URL origin, it won't be granted by `activeTab`, which is an intentional restriction enforced since Chrome 45, see https://crbug.com/826433.