# using background.js service_worker on about:blank page with matchAboutBlank:true not working, any workaround?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I run background.js (service_worker) in about:blank pages?

I want to do some JS inside Google Slide Presenter tab that opens as "about:blank" (when launching presenter from fullscreen browser).

I set `"match_about_blank" : true` for **content_scripts** and inside background.js I also tried using `matchAboutBlank: true` which didn't help.

I read that [activeTab doesn't work with about:blank pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59166046/using-tabs-executescript-in-iframe#comment104620637_59166046) in another post, is there any other way I can achieve this?

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Google Slide Presenter",
    "description": "Highlight speaker notes with background colour",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "icons": {
        "16": "/images/icon-16x16.png",
        "32": "/images/icon-32x32.png",
        "48": "/images/icon-48x48.png",
        "128": "/images/icon-128x128.png"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "/images/icon-16x16_black.png",
            "32": "/images/icon-32x32_black.png",
            "48": "/images/icon-48x48_black.png",
            "128": "/images/icon-128x128_black.png"
        }
    },
    "content_scripts":[{
     "matches": ["https://docs.google.com/*"],
     "match_about_blank" : true,
     "css": ["somecss.css"]
    }],
    
    "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "activeTab",
        "scripting",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "https://docs.google.com/*"
    ]

}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete' && /^http/.test(tab.url)) {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: { tabId: tabId },
            files: ["./foreground.js"],
            matchAboutBlank: true,
            
        })
            
            .then(() => {
                console.log("INJECTED THE FOREGROUND SCRIPT.");
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
});
```

**foreground.js**

```
document.querySelector(".punch-viewer-speakernotes-text-body-scrollable").style.backgroundColor='yellow';
```

**UPDATE - Able to run the JS but still with errors:**
using content_scripts to load the js

```
"content_scripts":[{
     "matches": ["https://docs.google.com/*"],
     "match_about_blank" : true,
     "css": ["progressbar.css"],
        "js": ["foreground.js"],
     "all_frames":true,
     "match_origin_as_fallback":true,
        "run_at": "document_start"
```

Using in foreground.js

```
setTimeout(function() {

  const container = document.getElementsByClassName('punch-viewer-speakernotes-text-body-zoomable')[0];
    
    if (container.textContent.includes('Speaker')) {
         document.querySelector(".punch-viewer-speakernotes-text-body-scrollable").style.backgroundColor='yellow';
    console.log('Speaker is contained in element');
    } else {
    console.log('Speaker is NOT contained in element');
         document.querySelector(".punch-viewer-speakernotes-text-body-scrollable").style.backgroundColor='blue';
    }

}, 5000);
```

CONSOLE:

> Speaker is contained in element
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'textContent') at foreground.js:5:19
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'textContent') at foreground.js:5:19

Comment: Add `"all_frames":true` and `"match_origin_as_fallback":true` to content_scripts in manifest.json. Note that the background service worker runs only in one place: in the hidden background context.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm, tried with both added but unfortunately it made no difference. I even tried adding '"run_at": "document_start",' . 
I used the background service from a chrome extension tutorial, as I'm only learning and didn't manage to load the .js from content_script, if there is a better way pls let me know, thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, the .css always worked but not the .js, which I need as I want to address some DOM elements to inspect text and insert text. Thanks @wOxxOm

Comment: Last attempt I tried loading the js from within content_scripts but in the console I get the error `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')"`  but running this .js manually in the console works just fine `document.querySelector(".punch-viewer-speakernotes-text-body-scrollable").style.backgroundColor='yellow';` I'm out of ideas.

Comment: It probably means the element appears after your content script runs. You can use setInterval or MutationObserver to wait for it, but there's actually no need for js at all if you just want to override the background color.

Comment: Thanks, ultimately I need to use JS as I want to insert text into speaker notes div. Where/how do I insert the setInterval or MutationObserver? Into the background.js or foreground.js? @wOxxOm

Comment: Thanks just figured it out loading js via content_scripts and insert the setinterval, however it's executing the js. contiously and with the interval i.e. every second it also generates still the same error in the console, strange. i only want it to run once and without producing error, feels like we are close :)

Comment: If you only want it to execute once, use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)

Comment: Thanks @ThomasMueller, brilliant. The only issue I still have is that when the js executes successfully it also afterwards produces twice the error
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'textContent')` within the if statement `if (container.textContent.includes('Speaker')) {`  as if it runs three times, once successfully and then two attempts while not having access, any ideas?